# Combine :ref: and ``code`` in rst with Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In Sphinx, how do I combine `:ref:` and ``` ``code`` ```? I want to have something like `` :ref:`name <target>` ``, but I want `name` to be escaped like ``` ``code`` ```.

Comment: Regarding backticks in inline code: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-do-i-escape-a-backtick-in-markdown

Comment: @mzjn that works, except it doesn't seem to work with two backticks, like \`\`code\`\`.